# Validate form after Click with jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have 3 forms in the same page and I want to validate when I click the button, but I have to click twice.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".form_foo").submit(function (e) {
        salvaformRisposta($(this).attr('id'));
        e.preventDefault(e);
    });
});

function validateForm(form_id) {
    $("#"+form_id).validate({
        rules: {
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            salvaformRisposta(form);
        }
    });
}
```

UPDATE:
I resolved with

```
$(".form_foo").each(function(key, form) {
    validateForm(form.id);
});
//
$(".form_foo").submit(function (e) {
    console.dir($(this).attr('id'));
    validateForm($(this).attr('id'));
    e.preventDefault(e);
});
```

Comment: provide pls your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#your_form_id').validate({
        rules: {
            ....
        }, messages: {
             ...
        }, submitHandler: function (form) {
         //insert here your code if validation is ok
       }
    }
});
```

insert this snippet in a forEach

Comment: And what i have to call with thsi funciton ? `$(".form_foo").submit(function (e) {
            salvaformRisposta($(this).attr('id'));
            e.preventDefault(e);
        });`

Comment: you do not need it. Validation will be working fine when you specify validate method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    validateForm('form_Id');
});
```

Try to Invoke validateForm() method in your document ready event.

substitute 'form_Id' with real form Id